# Without coercion to a list, can a data frame append a vector to itself in order to make new columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

```
column<-c(1, 2, 3)
data.frame("Test", column)
```

Outputs the following:

```
  X.Test. column
1    Test      1
2    Test      2
3    Test      3
```

but what I really want was this:

```
  X.Test. X1 X2 X3
1    Test  1  2  3
```

which I got from this:

```
column<-c(1, 2, 3)
data.frame("Test", as.list(column))
```

Is there any way to append a vector to a data frame like I have in the second example, without coercing the vector to a list? It feels like a hack to get something that ought to have a more natural way to bring about. My first thought was `cbind`, but that likes to recycle the first element.

Comment: have you tried this? column<-c(1, 2, 3);  x <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 4)); x[1,] <- c("Test", column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually think that coercion to list is relatively elegant, but here are two alternatives:

1. Via matrix population

```
data.frame("test", matrix(column, nrow = 1))
```

Result:

```
  X.test. X1 X2 X3
1    test  1  2  3
```

2. With `Reduce()`

```
Reduce(cbind, column, data.frame("test"))
```

Result

```
  X.test. x[[i]] x[[i]] x[[i]]
1    test      1      2      3
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `as.data.frame.list`

```
data.frame("Test", as.data.frame.list(column))
```

-output

```
    X.Test. X1 X2 X3
1    Test  1  2  3
```